# Mutt, Mailcap, Cygwin, Chrome: Opening HTML attachments in Mutt

Tags: cygwin, mutt

I am unable to open HTML attachments in Chrome when running Mutt on Cygwin. I view the message, then enter the list of attachments (`v`), then choose the `text/html` attachment and press `m` to execute mailcap's handling. The Chrome window opens successfully but nothing is in it. I instead see the following output in the terminal window:

```
[15132:12492:0717/120514.152:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)] Unable to move the cache: 5
[15132:12492:0717/120514.152:ERROR:cache_util.cc(134)] Unable to move cache folder C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ShaderCache\GPUCache to C:\Users\kutnic\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ShaderCache\old_GPUCache_000
[15132:12492:0717/120514.152:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(132)] Unable to create cache
[15132:12492:0717/120514.152:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(604)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
[15132:12492:0717/120514.210:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(103)] Failed to launch GPU process.
```

---

Some relevant configurations:

`~/.muttrc`

```
auto_view text/html # view html automatically
alternative_order text/html text/plain text/enriched  # show html first,for  testing
```

`~/.mailcap`

```
text/html; "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe" '%s'; description=HTML Text; nametemplate=%s.html
text/html; w3m -I %{charset} -T text/html; copiousoutput;
```

---

```
$ mutt -v
Mutt 1.8.3 (2017-05-23)
Copyright (C) 1996-2016 Michael R. Elkins and others.
Mutt comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `mutt -vv'.
Mutt is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `mutt -vv' for details.

System: CYGWIN_NT-10.0 2.8.2(0.313/5/3) (x86_64)
```

---

```
$ cygcheck -V
cygcheck (cygwin) 2.8.2
```

Chrome:

```
Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert path to windows format with `cygpath -w` before passing it to chrome

```
/etc/mailcap

text/html; "/cygdrive/c/Program Files \(x86\)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe" `cygpath -w %s`; needsterminal;
```